# XMLサイトマップをアップすることができません

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

※かなり知識が少なく、わかりにくい文面になっているかもしれないですが、ご了承ください。
Google XML Sitemapsを機能させたく考えておりますが、機能しないため、質問させていただいております。

プラグインの「Custom Permalinks」を利用しております。
https://ja.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/

このプラグインを使用したままだと
Google XML Sitemapsが機能しません。
それ以外のサイトマップ用のプラグインを試してみましたが、
どれも改善しなかったです。

「Custom Permalinks」のプラグインを削除してしまうと
今まで作ったページリンク切れになってしまいますが、
リンク切れページを301リダイレクトしていくしかないでしょうか。
恐れ入りますが、ご教示よろしくお願いいたします。

①　直下の.htaccessです。

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^http://belleclinic.com/rebelle/sp/
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://rebelle.tokyo/$1 [R=301,L]

AddHandler x-httpd-php70 .php
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/chz1167002/html/wp/
<FilesMatch "^(\.htaccess|\.htpasswd|php\.ini|.*\.sql|.*\.log|.*\.cron|.*\.inc|.*\.phps|.*\.yml)$">
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<Files ~ "\.pdf$">
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
</Files>

Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

# BEGIN WordPress
# `BEGIN WordPress` から `END WordPress` までのディレクティブ (行) は
# 動的に生成され、WordPress フィルターによってのみ修正が可能です。
# これらのマーカー間にあるディレクティブへのいかなる変更も上書きされてしまいます。
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

②　wpフォルダ直下の.htaccessです。

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php70 .php
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/chz1167003/html/
<FilesMatch "^(\.htaccess|\.htpasswd|php\.ini|.*\.sql|.*\.log|.*\.cron|.*\.inc|.*\.phps|.*\.yml)$">
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: 「Custom Permalinks」の設定に問題がある可能性はありませんか？
『Google XML Sitemapsが機能しません』というのは、どんな現象が起きている事なのですか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu様　ご確認ありがとうございます。sitemap.xmlをアップロードすることができず困っております。エラーコードは上記質問文に加筆しておりますので、恐れ入りますが、ご確認いただけますでしょうか。